# Make vodka with baking yeast?

Tags: vodka

Is it possible to use normal yeast from tesco (for baking) to make vodka?

I want to try making it in a 2 litre bottle since I'm space limited but could buy a 5 litre bottle in the future. How much of the yeast and how sugar would I need to add to a 2 litre bottle to make a decent amount of vodka? How much time would it take to brew and how strong would it be? Also whats the easiest way to make a DIY airlock thing?

I have absolutely no experience except from youtube videos so I could really use some hints. I want to place it in a cabinet in my desk so I'm space limited but I'm thinking of getting even eight 2 litre bottles and having a total output of 16 litres in the end depending how much vodka each bottle produces

Comment: See also https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/17422/bakers-yeast-and-distillation and https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/baking-yeast-for-brewing

Comment: What ingredients would you use to make this "Vodka" and what process are you aiming?  Distillation or just a fermentation?

Comment: I am going to close this as it is off topic for home brewing. Yes you could make a basic wash using bakers yeast but it would be far from ideal. For more details look here: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Vodka but be warned home distilled vodka can be very dangerous and/or illegal. You need to check your local laws and also ensure you know how to avoid methanol and higher alcohols in your finished product as these can be highly toxic.

Answer (score 2):

As mention by EP, there is more to Vodka than just adding yeast to something. The Homebrewing Q&A doesn't address distilling questions in general, only products resulting from fermentation process.  However, I can answer your other questions.

Wine or Beer Yeast is usually cheap to buy and produces better results, so I wouldn't make anything from baking yeast.  I recommend using Wine Yeast to reach higher alcohol content.  [This yeast](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast-bank/wlp099-super-high-gravity-ale-yeast) can reach 25% of alcohol, not all yeasts can reach that high.  All quantities required and instructions are indicated on the package. Usually, a package is made for a 20L batch, so 2L would require 1/10 of a package.

If you want to make your own airlock, you can take a look at this post for details: [Homemade Airlock](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4285/homemade-airlock#comment24249_4285)

If you know nothing about distilling, please don't try it, there is a danger of [methanol poisoning](http://www.abc.net.au/local/audio/2013/06/13/3781104.htm).  At least, read and learn about it on sites likes this one : [http://homedistiller.org](http://homedistiller.org/intro/steps) and if you do it one day, do it right (I have seen so much garbage on YouTube!).

Comment: This is a better answer than min have up voted it. As far as methanol is concerned tho I think for very small batches you may not get something realy bad even if you do not trow away the first part of the distillate. If you do trow away the first part of the distillate you should be good.

Comment: The notion of methanol poisoning is almost non-existent in yeast/sugar/water based brews. I have yet to recover any significant amounts of methanol in a distillation from "sensibly" fermented sources using yeast and sugar or sugar based solutions. Most methanol comes from i) external sources (eg denatured industrial alcohol), ii)from distilling ferments that are less than scrupulously made up or iii) are made from fruits (particularly stoned fruits) with higher levels of Pectinesterase.

Answer (score 1):

Brewing is only a smal part of making vodka. You also ned to destil what you have brewed. Regular baking yeast can make alcohol but it is better to use yeast for wine. This yeast will give you a higer alcohol content before you start to distil. If you want something drinkable after destilling use a charcoal filter in the end and throw away the first part of what you distil. Note that destilling alcohol  can be illegal where you are.

Comment: How do i go around distilling alchohol. Also its not illegal if no body finds out, right?

Comment: See the links supplied by Philippe. And as Philippe say do much research before attempting this.

Comment: Okay thanks ill look up more things about it. Would one of those 48 hour yeast for alchohol things from amazon be good to use? Also i read you need to carbon filter, is there a diy way to do that?

Comment: That yeast is probably fine for vodka. They are not necessarily very good for wine tho, but distilling and filtering should remove most of the bad flavor it makes. And yes you can make charcoal filters diy. Activated charcoal can be made by you or bought in pet stores. are videos on you-tube for how to.

Comment: One more thing I would never ever dear to distill alcohol around an open flame.  So no gas stoves go electric preferably one without a thermostat.